# Replace part of filenames in all subdirectories with Python

Tags: python, file, rename, subdirectory

I am trying to replace a part of a filename with another for the files in all subdirectories.

I have managed to do this in the current folder my script is, but I need it to work for all child folders.

Here is the code I use to rename files in the current folder:

```
import os
path =  os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace("PART_TO_REPLACE", "NEW_PART"))
```

Here is my attempt to make it work for all subdirectories in my folder:

```
import os
path = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Python test"

for root,dirname,filename in os.walk(path):   
     for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(filename, filename.replace("PART_TO_REPLACE", "NEW_PART"))
```

Nothing is happening when I run the second script. My files are not renamed. I don't get any error message either.

My Python Shell pop-window shows:

```
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
======= RESTART: /Users/me/Desktop/Python test/Child Rename.py =======
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Is the code not behaving as expected? Edit the question with details of what you are expecting to occur vs what is occurring. BTW you are going to need to use recursion for this problem.

Comment: Hi Tim. The code is not doing anything, I don't even get an error message and my files have still the same names.

Comment: When looping over the return values from `os.walk`, you're ignoring the value of `root`. That's probably your problem. Maybe print out the values of `root` and `filenames` to see what they contain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(root, filename)
        os.rename(file, file.replace("PART_TO_REPLACE", "NEW_PART"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still get the same results with your code though